# External CSS link is not working in codeIgniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried base_url() function, But I didn't understand where am I wrong?
I have also mentioned - `$this->load->helper ('URL');` in function `abc()` in controller.
Here is my code,

`<link href="<?PHP echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS"/>`

Comment: I added my answer hope it helped

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/dist/flex-dist.css');?>" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code to link your css :

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

make sure you have configure the CI configuration properly : 
CONFIG.PHP

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

AUTOLOAD.PHP

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the way you are referencing the css file. You can use this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or you can use this:

```
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Notice the / at the start of the link, this means the browser will look from the base of your website url (your domain). If you miss it out it will use the relative part of the url, so if you are referencing a controller it will assume this is a sub folder for the location of the css file too.

You are better off with the base_url format given first, if you are using a local host for development then you will not have any problems with the url base. If you app is moved to a sub folder on another site or with a sub domain etc you will not have any problems either.

So base_url is the way to go here. More info in the docs.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url

Comment: You edited your question while I was answering - I hope it still helps.

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking you have not set tour base_url if your base url shows Ip address in links your css will not work

You need to set this value

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```

Head

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Make sure your assets folder out side of application

```
application

assets
```

A good thing is to also autoload url helper lower case.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```